# Inserting an SQL table into a tree

Tags: python, sql, tkinter, tree, listbox

I managed to fine a piece of code that for the most part does what I want it to do, except the original code used a list to insert the data into the tree. I want the data that will be inserted to be called from an SQL table and outputted into the correct columns. My coding thus far looks like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import sqlite3
class MultiColumnListbox(object):
    """use a ttk.TreeView as a multicolumn ListBox"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.tree = None
        self._setup_widgets()
        self._build_tree()

    def _setup_widgets(self):
        s = """\click on header to sort by that column
        to change width of column drag boundary
        """
        msg = ttk.Label(wraplength="4i", justify="left", anchor="n",
            padding=(10, 2, 10, 6), text=s)
        msg.pack(fill='x')
        container = ttk.Frame()
        container.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        # create a treeview with dual scrollbars
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=getvariablesC, show="headings")
        vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical",
            command=self.tree.yview)
        hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="horizontal",
            command=self.tree.xview)
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set,
            xscrollcommand=hsb.set)
        self.tree.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew', in_=container)
        vsb.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='ns', in_=container)
        hsb.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='ew', in_=container)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def _build_tree(self):
        for col in getvariablesC:
            self.tree.heading(col, text=col.title(),
                command=lambda c=col: sortby(self.tree, c, 0))
            # adjust the column's width to the header string
            self.tree.column(col,
                width=tkFont.Font().measure(col.title()))
    def sqlcode():
        db = sqlite3.connect('File')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql1="Select * FROM ProductTable"
        cursor.execute(sql1)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        count = (len(result))
        for item in result:
            self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=item)
            # adjust column's width if necessary to fit each value
            for ix, val in enumerate(item):
                col_w = tkFont.Font().measure(val)
                if self.tree.column(getvariablesC[ix],width=None)<col_w:
                    self.tree.column(getvariablesC[ix], width=col_w)
        cursor.close()

    sqlcode()

    getvariablesC=    ["CustomerID","Title","Name","Address1","Address2","Town","County","PostCode","STDCode","HomeNo","MobileNo","Email","Source","Month","Year"]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Multicolumn Treeview/Listbox")
    listbox = MultiColumnListbox()
    root.mainloop()
```

The main problem I am having Is that `self` is not being defined when the coding is run, but I am unsure of what is causing the error :

`NameError: global name 'self' is not defined`

Comment: Looks like line level error. In your case there are MultiColumnListbox class and several independent methods. Please, add spaces (tab) before methods to fix indentation.

Comment: It appears the indentation wasn't correct. It should be now, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing `self` in the function definition. You should change:

```
def sqlcode():
```

to

```
def sqlcode(self):
```

Comment: I have made that adjustment but it now comes up with the error`NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

Comment: you have to keep correct `indentation` under your class. For ex, number spaces for `def __init__(self):` should be same as `def sqlcode(self):`